# How to update the table when a certain row is deleted using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rows

I want to update the index when the Rows are deleted in the Table.
For e.g. I delete row 1, then the rows 2 and 3 should become 1 and 2, so on.

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please post an example of what the HTML for the table would look like?

Answer (score 2):

Well you dont need to do anything! when ever a row is deleted from dom, automatically the row index is changed.

if you want to closely examine you can hook an mutationevent DOMNodeRemoved and see whats happening, or just keep a break point after delete and verify the row count and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete jQuery solution:

Test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/E46Cz/). Just click on a row to delete it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js""></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {

            $('tr').click(function () {

                $(this).remove()
                recountRows();
            });


            var recountRows = function () {
                var index = 1;

                $('.index').each(function () {
                    $(this).html(index);
                    index++;
                });
            }


        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">1</td><td>table text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">2</td><td>table text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">3</td><td>table text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">4</td><td>table text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">5</td><td>table text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">6</td><td>table text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">7</td><td>table text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index">8</td><td>table text</td>
        </tr>


    </table>


</body>
</html>
```